# MySQL Query run through NodeJS and Express returning Buffer data

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

very new to JavaScript and API building. I'm writing a simple address verification system and I'm running into an issue where the response sends the buffer data in addition to the response of the columns that I want to query. I know that I should be returning rows and fields, but do not know how to fit it into the code.

This is what I currently have for the main query:

```
app.get("/addresses/api/find/", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const address1 = req.query.Address1;
    const address2 = req.query.Address2;
    const city = req.query.City;
    const state = req.query.State;
    const zip = req.query.ZipCode;
    
    console.log(req.body);
    const findAddress = await pool.query ("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE Address1 = ?", 
    [
        address1,
    ]
    );
    
    res.json({
        status: "Success: 200",
        message: "There was a match to your address.",
        findAddress
        });

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
        }    
    })
```

And this is a part of what is returned when there is no exact match:

```
{
"status": "Success: 200",
"message": "There was a match to your address.",
"findAddress": [
    [],
    [
        {
            "_buf": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    1,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    6,
                    47,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    3,
                    100,
```

I'm still working on the logic to reject an empty set, but I have not gotten that far, yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert data value to string type ,then you can see results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to limit the output to only the rows by dropping by variable into brackets and requesting only that information back.

```
console.log(req.body, "Get request reached.");
const [address] = await pool.query ("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE (Address1, City, State, ZipCode) = (?, ?, ?, ?)",
  [
    address1,
    city,
    state,
    zip
  ],
);
```

It gave me this response:

```
{
  "status": "Success: 200",
  "message": "There was a match to your address.",
  "address": [
    {
      "id": 112,
      "Address1": "16 Blue Sage Circle",
      "Address2": "",
      "City": "Atlanta",
      "State": "GA",
      "ZipCode": "30318-1030"
    }
  ]
}
```